# Verifying The Solution of a Certain Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking for the solution of the differential equation $x\space dx + (sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right))^2(y\space dx  - x \space dy) = 0.$ I don't know the answer, but I tried to get its answer.

My work:

I recognize that the differential equation above is a homogenous type, so we need the substitutions $x = vy$ and $dx = vdy + ydv$ to get the solutions to these type of differential equations.

Armed with these hints, the differential equation $x\space dx + (sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right))^2(y\space dx  - x \space dy) = 0$ becomes:

$$x\space dx + \left(sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)^2(y\space dx  - x \space dy) = 0$$

$$x\space dx + y \left(sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)^2 \space dx  - x \left(sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)^2 \space dy) = 0$$

$$vy\space (vdy + ydv) + y \left(sin \left(\frac{y}{vy}\right)\right)^2 \space (vdy + ydv)  - vy \left(sin \left(\frac{y}{vy}\right)\right)^2 \space dy = 0$$

$$v^2y\space dy + vy^2\space dv + vy\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2 dy+  y^2\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2 dv - vy\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2 dy = 0$$

$$v^2y\space dy + vy^2\space dv +  y^2\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2 dv = 0$$

It is apparent that we can put $v$'s on left side and $y$'s on right side. It looks like this:

$$v^2y\space dy + vy^2\space dv +  y^2\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2 dv = 0$$

$$ vy^2\space dv +  y^2\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2 dv = -v^2y\space dy$$

Divide both left and right sides of the equation by $y^2$, it becomes:
$$ v\space dv +  \left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2 dv = -\frac{v^2}{y}\space dy$$

Divide both left and right sides of the equation by $v^2$, it becomes:
$$ \frac{v}{dv} +  \frac{\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2}{v^2} dv = -\frac{1}{y}\space dy$$

Get the integrals of the terms of the differential equation above, it becomes:

$$ \int \frac{v}{dv} +  \int \frac{\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{v} \right) \right)^2}{v^2} dv = \int -\frac{1}{y}\space dy$$

$$ln \space v + \left(-\frac{1}{2v} + \frac{sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right)}{4}\right) = - ln \space y + c$$

Then, rearranging the expression above to make sense:
$$ln \space v + \left(-\frac{1}{2v} + \frac{sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right)}{4}\right) = - ln \space y + c$$
$$ -\frac{1}{2v} + \frac{sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right)}{4} = -ln \space v - ln \space y + c$$

$$ -\frac{1}{2v} + \frac{sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right)}{4} = -ln \space v - ln \space y + ln \space c$$

$$ -\frac{1}{2v} + \frac{sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right)}{4} = ln \space v^{-1} + ln \space y^{-1} + ln \space c$$

$$ -\frac{1}{2v} + \frac{sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right)}{4} = ln \left(\frac{c}{vy} \right)$$

Then do this:

$$ -\frac{1}{2v} + \frac{sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right)}{4} = ln \left(\frac{c}{vy} \right)$$

$$\frac{-4 + 2v \left( sin \left(\frac{2}{v}\right) \right) }{8v} = ln \left( \frac{c}{vy} \right)$$

Returning the original values, it becomes:

$$\frac{-4 + 2\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \left( sin \left(\frac{2}{\frac{x}{y}}\right) \right) }{8 \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)} = ln \left( \frac{c}{\left(\frac{x}{y} \right) y} \right)$$

$$\left(\frac{y}{8x}\right) \left( -4 + \frac{2x}{y} sin \left( \frac{2y}{x} \right) \right) = ln \left( \frac{c}{x}\right) $$

$$\frac{-y}{2x} + \frac{1}{4} sin \left( \frac{2y}{x} \right) = ln \left( \frac{c}{x}\right) $$

Ultimately, the solution of the differential equation  I got is:

$$xe^{\left(\frac{-y}{2x} + \frac{1}{4} sin \left( \frac{2y}{x} \right) \right)} = c$$

I honestly can't verify the answer, but did I do it right? Is my solution correct?

Comment: This seems to be very correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  It is? My solution is correct?

Comment: To me, it is ! It could (may be) be done a bit faster but it is good work.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Gee! thanks for the help!

Comment: You are very welcome !